# Error concatination strings by memory allocation

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am trying to concat strings inside array with one another using memory allocation. But I get the error, any ideas what causes it? Thank you.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void) {

const char *str[8] = { "one", "two", "three", "four",
    "five", "six", "seven", "eight" };
char *concat;
int total_size = 0;
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    total_size += strlen(str[i]) - 1;  // I put -1 for '\0' of each word.

concat = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (total_size + 1));  // +1 for '\0'

concat = '\0';
for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    strcat(concat, str[i]);

}

printf("%s\n", concat);
free(concat);
system("pause");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: "The error?" That one or this one?

Comment: What about `concat = '\0';`, `concat` being a `char*` :) ?

Comment: total count should be `size_t` or `unsigned long int` and not `int`. You should not cast `malloc`. And there is no Error, is just `Segmentation fault`

Comment: This line `malloc(sizeof(char) * (total_size + 1))` change it to `malloc(total_size + 1)` because does the same

Comment: What exactly does `concat = '\0';` for you?? should be `concat[size] = '\0';`

Comment: I think you should use `calloc` here because of `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`. [Try this](http://ideone.com/IcaEaW). After you fix your code, try to run a memory check tool and you will understand

Comment: 1) Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C. 2) `sizeof(char)` is **defined** to yield `1`. It is useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong here

```
total_size += strlen(str[i]) - 1;  // I put -1 for '\0' of each word.
```

remove the `- 1`.

In addition

```
concat = '\0';
```

should be

```
concat[0] = '\0';
```

Comment: To further clarify, `strlen(...)` returns the number of characters up to and not including the first null character.